# php echo show alert message

Tags: alert, message, show

This is my button trigger alert

```
<div id="alert1" data-target="#alert1" class="qdr-alert alert bg-primary top left white">
                    <strong>Well done!</strong> You are using a stronger theme!
                </div>
```

Left Top

But i dont want to button. I want to show alert in action php page print alert message to show.

```
//Quadra Alert on page
    $('.qdr-alert-trigger').each(function(){
        var self = $(this),
            target = $(self).data('target'),
            timer;
        $(self).on('click', function(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $(target).fadeOut(0).stop().clearQueue();
            setTimeout( function(){$(target).fadeIn(300)},1);
            timer = setTimeout( function(){$(target).fadeOut(300);},3000);
        });
    });
```

what can i do for direct show alert message. just i want to use this without javascript. i want to directly print message.

Comment: do you mean without using `setTimeout()`?

Comment: No. I want to show like normal alert message without button.

Comment: <div id="alert1" data-target="#alert1" class="qdr-alert alert bg-primary top left white"> <strong>Well done!</strong> You are using a stronger theme! </div> like this

Comment: You could use `echo "<script>alert('$message')</script>";`. If you want to show model window, you need JS anyway